# How to preserve input value when checkbox is checked Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How can we preserve the value of the input box whose corresponding checkbox is checked, and if the corresponding checkbox is not checked then clear input value from `form`?

```
<form onsubmit="finalSubmission">

<input type="checkbox" id="yourBox1" />
<input type="text" id="yourText1" />
<br>
<hr>

<input type="checkbox" id="yourBox2" />
<input type="text" id="yourText2" />
<br>
<hr>

<input type="checkbox" id="yourBox3" />
<input type="text" id="yourText3" />
<br>
<hr>
<input type="checkbox" id="yourBox4" />
<input type="text" id="yourText4" />
<br>
<hr>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

I know I can do this way, but is there any other alternative approach for this. This is quite a length approach

```
function finalSubmission(event){
event.preventDefault();
let firstInputField;
let checkBox1 = document.getElementById("yourBox1");
    if (checkBox1.checked == true){
        firstInputField = true
    } else {
        firstInputField = false
    }
if(!firstInputField){
  document.getElementById('yourText').value = "";
}
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you wish to keep these values AFTER the form has been submitted?

Comment: Also - what does your `finalSubmission` return?

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```js
function finalSubmission() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    !document.getElementById("yourBox" + i).checked ? document.getElementById("yourText" + i).value = "" : null;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="yourBox1" />
<input type="text" id="yourText1" />
<br>
<hr>

<input type="checkbox" id="yourBox2" />
<input type="text" id="yourText2" />
<br>
<hr>

<input type="checkbox" id="yourBox3" />
<input type="text" id="yourText3" />
<br>
<hr>
<input type="checkbox" id="yourBox4" />
<input type="text" id="yourText4" />
<br>
<hr>
<button type="submit" onclick="finalSubmission">Submit</button>
```